# Lookup field from Case to Order doesn't detect any Order

Tags: lookup, standard-objects, data-model

I have created a simple lookup field from Case to Order. No lookup filter criterias are implicated so far. I have created two orders in database, and when I try to attach this Case to one of those Order, already created, I can't. In the search layout, doesn't appear any of them.

Thanks in advance guys!
Regards,
Endrit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your Order Name in the lookup field and then click on the magnifying glass icon.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: Yeah, I had, to put the correct Order Number, in the text box, and than perform the lookup search. 
Thank you.